# How to install sheetJS

Tags: javascript, installation, export-to-excel, sheetjs

Hey guys I might be completely dumb but I can't download the sheetJS lib. I have read the "installation" paragraph on github but I don't understand. [Here is the link](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) to the git. I don't have npm or bower on my pc btw and I'm using vanilla JS. I watched youtube videos about sheetJS and what I need is this js file : **xlsx.full.min.js**. I tried to add the tag (`<script lang="javascript" src="dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>`) in my html file but it didn't work.

I am trying to export an HTML table to an Excel file adding some style. If you know another way to do it with JS don't hesitate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all, you are not dumb.

just put this script tag in your HTML, and you are good to go.
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>`